# Open custom Android url scheme from Asp .Net throws error using Response.Redirect but not with hyperlink click

Tags: android, asp.net, url-scheme

I'm trying to open up our Android app from one of our websites by doing `Response.Redirect("myapp://?sitename=blah&IP=blah&pass=blah)`. But when this gets called I get the

```
You do not have permission to open this page. 
myapp://?sitename=blah&IP=blah&pass=blah
```

error. However, when I create a `HyperLink` and set `NavigateUrl="myapp://?sitename=blah&IP=blah&pass=blah"`, clicking on the link works and successfully opens the app.

But, we want to avoid creating a hyperlink on the webpage because we don't want the password easily readable in the markup.

Does anybody know why it would work one way but not the other?